# How to avoid returning NULL on error if it has to return something? (in C)

Tags: c, error-handling, null

I've stumbled on articles [here](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare) and [here](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare), that says its good programming practice to never return NULL. But for functions that need to return something, what should it return? a value of `-1` is not going to cut it since lets say we have function:

```
char *return_some_string(int input) {
    /* do something */

    if (error) 
        return some_thing_not_null; 
}
```

How do you get round this problem?

Comment: You ignore the bad advice.  Returning NULL on failure is the Right Thing for this sort of function.

Comment: For some reason questions that start with “I have read that …” often fail to cite their sources. The thing having been read is usually ludicrous and we would like to understand whether the reader misunderstood what was being said or whether it is just a case of bad documentation, which can happen. Not citing the source makes “I have read that …” frustrating and uninteresting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I've stumbled on articles that says its good programming practice to never return NULL.

Unconditionally stating that shows the quality of that article. **Burn it.**

> But for functions that need to return something, what should it return?

`NULL`. Conceptually, that's the "invalid pointer", "pointer that points to nothing", whatever. There's a very good reason it's in the language.

Comment: darn you beat me to it :) lol

Answer (score 3):

in C it's perfectly normal to return NULL..

in fact, the mallc, the C library returns NULL at times...

you have a pointer, it's fine to be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be exotic, you can do what MS does:

```
#define INVALID_POINTER_VALUE ((void*)-1l)
```

So you can return and test against it. Though `NULL` has good reasons behind. Note the suffix: the value has to be `long` type before conversion, or any other type that matches pointer in size.